# Application does not operate correctly when installed

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsbundle

I'm having a strange issue with my application for Mac OS X. I have a process that runs in a secondary thread. The process repeats a certain action a user-specified number of times in a for loop.

With each iteration of the for loop, there is a string that is initialized with the contents of a strings file. If the content of the strings file equals `"YES"` then the loop breaks (the file is set to `"NO"` by default). When the user wants to stop the loop, they hit the "Stop" button which sets the contents of the file to `"YES"`.

This actually works great when I run the application in Xcode and when I export the application as a .app. The problem occurs when I actually turn the application into a pkg and install it. The stop function no longer operates correctly. I'm pretty stumped as to what the issue is. I'm initializing all my references to my file using `[NSBundle mainBundle]` so I should be referencing the file in my application bundle.

EDIT: I actually decided to switch to checking an atomic BOOL value within the loop that I change when the stop button is pressed. This seems to be a simpler solution for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular users do not have permission to modify applications installed in the /Application folder for very good security reasons. Also, signed apps (ie, any app sold through the App Store) cannot be modified without invalidating your signed code.

**Never, ever, ever** rely on the application bundle being modifiable. It's never supposed to be. **Always** [use standard user data folders](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/ManagingFIlesandDirectories/ManagingFIlesandDirectories.html) like "~/Library/Application Support/" or "~/Library/Caches/" for app-related, non-document files.

As to your general approach, repeatedly polling a file - especially in a tight loop - is a *lot* of disk activity. "Laptop Killah" would be a good name for the app. :-) You should consider changing this approach altogether. If you provide more detail in another question (what you're doing and why) and ask for suggestions, I'm almost positive there'll be a number of better ways that don't chew through your users' battery charge like crack-addled rats in a grocery store.

Also, I'm guessing you never check to see if your file is written successfully. The standard -writeToURL/File:... methods return a BOOL to signal success or failure as well as set an NSError (if you pass a pointer to one) with further details. Get into the habit of *not* ignoring this. In this case, you might've found your own answer because you'd have known just where your code is breaking. From there, it wouldn't have been a huge leap to figure out why.